# Minimal svg definition of a polygon with empty squares inside

Tags: svg, polygon, fill

I'm searching for the simplest definition in svg of a squared number '8', like in the figure below (black inside).

[image]

Ways that come to my mind are made of filling several polygons (minimal would be 1 black rectangle and 2 white squares). Is there a way to define it with a single command, specifying all the vertices?

Update: the purpose, BTW, is to create a font from svg files like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overlap multiple paths in a single path element and using the fill-rule "evenodd" the intersecting areas will crop. like so:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path stroke-width="0" d="M20,20 h20 v35 h-20z M25,25 h10 v10 h-10z M25,40 h10 v10 h-10z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
</svg>
```

Here is a [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-svg-fill-rule-property/) that explains how it works.

Comment: Good and artistic explanation in the link provided. BTW, what's the meaning of the 'z' in the 'h-10z' parameter?

Comment: the z is used to close the subpath that starts with the M

Comment: when I delete them, the result is the same...  may be it's the default value.

Comment: "Closing a path" draws a straight line from the last point back to the first point on the subpath.  It is usually only necessary if you are stroking the path.